# PresenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy method using WebElement instead of By

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using PageFactory to locate elements and I need to wait till element is not exist.

My wait method is the following:

```
public void waitForElementIsNoExists(By by) {
    try {

        FluentWait<WebDriver> myWait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
                .withTimeout(timeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .pollingEvery(50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)
                .ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class)
                .ignoring(TimeoutException.class);
        myWait.until(ExpectedConditions.not(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(by)));
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        System.out.println("Timed out after default time out. Page is not responding after " + timeOut + "sec.");
    }
}
```

PresenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy implementation from Selenium API:

```
   public static ExpectedCondition<List<WebElement>> presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(final By locator) {
        return new ExpectedCondition<List<WebElement>>() {
            public List<WebElement> apply(WebDriver driver) {
                List<WebElement> elements = ExpectedConditions.findElements(locator, driver);
                return elements.size() > 0 ? elements : null;
            }

            public String toString() {
                return "presence of any elements located by " + locator;
            }
        };
    }
```

However, because of PageFactory, I need to use WebElement instead of by.

How can I rewrite PresenceOfAllElementsLocated method to get WebElement as a parameter? Reason, PageFactory can avoid StaleElementException.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to rewrite a built-in method. If you have a single `WebElement`, you can check that it doesn't exist (or at least that's it's no longer visible on the page) using:

```
myWait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf(element));
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont use pageFactory use below code

1.In your page object class define web element as below

By element=By.xpath("//select[@id='******']");

WebElement element;

2.Create a CommonMethod.java class and write below 2 method

private static WebDriverWait jsWait=new WebDriverWait(driver,60);

public static WebElement getWebelement(WebDriver driver, By by)
 {

WebElement ele = null;

```
      try {
         ele =Findelement(by);

      } catch (StaleElementReferenceException ignored) {
          Findelement(by);
      }
      return ele;
    }
```

public static WebElement Findelement(By by)

```
 {

     jsWait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated((by)));
      WebElement ele = driver.findElement(by);
    return ele;
 }
```

3.Call this method

CommonClass.getWebelement(driver,element);